# MySQL Starting Speed Issue

Tags: mysql, performance, service

I have MySQL 5.6 running on a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine, it runs successfully, I do have some speed issues when creating tables, its extremely slow, however this issue is to do with starting the MySQL service when the server restarts, I would expect MYSQL56 service to start within a minute or two at the most, however it can hang for up to 30 minutes, I know it eventually starts, but sometimes I have to kill the process and attempt to restart the service again, sometimes it can take 10 minutes or sometimes it can take longer and I get so twitchy I have to kill it.

Does anybody know what I should be looking into to try and fix this issue?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I think maybe if I can fix this it might also fix my slow table creation?

Cheers

Comment: How fast is it when you Stop and reStart it?

Comment: Hi Rick,Thanks for the comment, interesting question, I will have to do this later when the server is not is use as much. I will let you know the outcome.